# In a change of coordinates, what is the physical meaning of the new partial derivatives when one coordinate didn't change?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, coordinate-systems, change-of-variable

In a change of coordinates where one coordinate, the time, remains the same, I don't understand why the new partial derivatives for that coordinate are different. Let me show you:
The variable $ u(x,t) $ satisfies a particular PDE.
$(x,t)$ was changed to $(X,T)$ where
$$
X = f(x,t) \\
T = t
$$
Applying the chain rule, the derivatives of u can be written as:
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} =
\frac{\partial u}{\partial X} \frac{\partial X}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial T} \frac{\partial T}{\partial x}
= \frac{\partial u}{\partial X} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = 
\frac{\partial u}{\partial X} \frac{\partial X}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial T} \frac{\partial T}{\partial t}
 = \frac{\partial u}{\partial X} \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial T}
$$
So what what confuses me is the fact that, although $T = t$ in the new coordinate system, $\frac{\partial u}{\partial T} \neq \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$. Can anyone explain the physical meaning behind that?

Comment: $\frac{\partial u}{\partial T}$ means limit of $\frac{\Delta u}{\Delta T}$ at $\Delta T\to 0$ and $X={\rm const}$. $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$ means limit of $\frac{\Delta u}{\Delta t}$ at $\Delta t\to 0$ and $x={\rm const}$. $X={\rm const}$ and $x={\rm const}$ are not the same conditions, that's why $\frac{\partial u}{\partial T}\ne\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$

Comment: Thank you that helps!

Comment: Partial derivatives are sometimes denoted with a subscript for what's held fixed. For example, @IvanKaznacheyeu's explanation can be restated as thus: $\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial T}\right)_X\ne\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right)_x$ because holding $X$ fixed while varying $T$ is not equivalent to holding $x$ fixed while varying $t$.

Answer (score 1):

This is best explained by the notion of [directional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative). The derivative of $u \left(x , t\right)$ in the direction $\left(a , b\right)$ is the limit

\begin{equation}{\partial}_{\left(a , b\right)} u = \lim _{h \rightarrow  0} \frac{u \left(x+a h , t+b h\right)-u \left(x , t\right)}{h}\end{equation}

By definition,

\begin{equation}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = {\partial}_{\left(0 , 1\right)} u\end{equation}

But

\begin{equation}\frac{\partial u}{\partial T} = {\partial}_{\left({-{\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)}^{{-1}}} \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} , 1\right)} u\end{equation}

Indeed, suppose that one increases $ T$ by a small amount $\delta T$ while keeping $ X$ invariant, then $t$
increases by the amount $ \delta t = \delta T$, but

\begin{equation}0 = \delta X \approx \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \delta x+\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} \delta t\end{equation}

it means that $x$ increases by an amount

\begin{equation}\delta x \approx-{\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)}^{{-1}} \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} \delta T\end{equation}

So $\frac{\partial }{\partial  t}$ and $\frac{\partial }{\partial  T}$
are directional derivatives in two different spacetime directions.